# Rails nested .each not able to access top level variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each, ruby-on-rails-5

This code executes when I save a new Challenge, it then loops through all associated Users and creates Datapoints for each day in the Challenge.

Cohorts and Datapoints save just fine in this function, but the `|user|` variable from the first loop doesn't work in the nested loop. So when Datapoints get saved they all lack a `:user_id`.

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something about scope, or possibly the different ways that `.each` and `.each_with_index` behave, but I just can't seem to figure out the problem.

Controller snippet:

```
# loop through all associated users
    @user_list.each do |user|
        # create join
        cohort = Cohort.new(:user_id => user, :challenge_id => @challenge.id)
        if cohort.valid?
            cohort.save
        else
            @errors += cohort.errors
        end

        # for each date in range create an empty Datapoint
        date_range.each_with_index do |day, index|
            day_count = index + 1
            datapoint = Datapoint.new(:user_id => user, :challenge_id => @challenge.id, :date => day, :day => day_count)
            if datapoint.valid?
                datapoint.save
            else
                @errors += datapoint.errors
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Where and how is `date_range` defined?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding a `.id` to the `user` in `Datapoint.new(:user_id => user, :challenge_id => @challenge.id, :date => day, :day => day_count)`?

Comment: @JamesMilani That's what it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit is wrong because you're assigning a complex object to an integer

```
datapoint = Datapoint.new(:user_id => user, :challenge_id => @challenge.id, :date => day, :day => day_count)
```

If `Datapoint` actually `belongs_to user` you can do

```
datapoint = Datapoint.new(:user => user, :challenge_id => @challenge.id, :date => day, :day => day_count)
```

But if the `belongs_to` isn't defined, you need to store just the id of the user

```
datapoint = Datapoint.new(:user_id => user.id, :challenge_id => @challenge.id, :date => day, :day => day_count)
```

Comment: It was adding the id that fixed it. Thanks so much!